# How to keep UIscrollview frame fixed but dynamics bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, frame, bounds

I'd like to create image mask like following screenshot.

I put UIImageView in UIScrollView. and set the scroll view frame match the center white square.

[image: image mask]

in scrollview delegate, I changed the scrollview bounds. then we can see photo extend outside of the white border.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    self.imgScrollView.bounds = self.imageView.frame;
}
```

After zoom-in, from log I can see scrollview frame is changed too.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
                       withView:(UIView *)view
                        atScale:(CGFloat)scale {

    NSLog(@"= = = = = = = = = = =");
    [self logName:@"IMAGEVIEW" ofView:self.imageView];
    [self logName:@"SCROLLVIEW" ofView:self.imgScrollView];
}
```

If I set frame back to white square at delegate, the bounds will be set back too!   Then image outside of the white border won't be drawn.

If there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

No need to change bounds. just set scrollview clipsToBounds = NO.